# Django - unique_together option with override save method in form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to use the unique_together option when user save data within a form and not with the django admin.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ezApp(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True )
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated', auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    in_use = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'created_by'),)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.models import BaseModelFormSet
from ezApp.models import *

class BaseEzAppFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(BaseEzAppFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save_new(self, form, commit=True):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.created_by = self.user
        if commit:
             obj.save()
        return obj
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import *
from ezApp.models import *
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from django.http import HttpResponseServerError
from ezApp.forms import *

def createEzAppInstance(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            ezAppFormSet = modelformset_factory(ezApp, extra=1, fields=('name'), formset=BaseEzAppFormSet)
            formset = ezAppFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()

        return render_to_response("ezApp/manage_new_ezApp.html", {'formset': formset, 'title': "New App"}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    error_msg = u"You are not logged in"
    return HttpResponseServerError(error_msg)
```

With unique_together in the Meta of the model, the validation is working only inside django admin but not when I use the form to save new data.

Comment: Is it a copy/paste issue but the indentation of the Meta class should be the same as the fields in ezApp

Comment: Post the view code, are you validating the formset? Why are you using save_new in the formset instead of overriding the form's save() method and calling Super()?

Comment: Also post your form code!

Comment: the views and the forms are posted! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As msc points out you need to override the save method rather than writing your own.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = super(BaseEzAppFormSet, self).save(form, *args, commit=False, **kwargs)
    obj.created_by = self.user
    obj.save()
    return obj
```

It doesn't look like your save_new() method was ever being called in your view.

Comment: in fact I used new_save() to pass request.user from the form to the model to auto populate created_by during the creation of a new ezApp

Comment: I see that's what the code is for. I just don't see where you've used it. save_new() is never called. You're calling formset.save() not formset.save_new()

Comment: save_new() in a BaseModelFormSet overrides the save() of the model. I can assure you that its called. Thats what I understand from this article http://streamhacker.com/2010/03/01/django-model-formsets/

Comment: OK, looking at the source code, it looks like save_new() is called by save() (it doesn't override save). Your code might be easier to maintain if you included a call to super in your definition of save_new(). Anyway, I'm learning so +1 on the question from me (and I'll probably delete my answer - it's wrong).

Comment: Ok no problem, thank you for your help. I have learn something also with your answer. I think I will give up the unique_together in my app for now, and just stay with a unique=True in ezApp name field option, even if I would prefer to let different user to create app instances with the same name.